# How can I sum total of this value?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
        US_UserDataModel[] total_valD009 = pur_price_D009.Where(x => x.D009 > 0).ToArray(); //Total values
        US_UserDataModel[] g1 = total_valD009.Where(x => x.D009 <= 8).ToArray();            //Group1 = value '1-8'    Less$20,000
        US_UserDataModel[] g2 = total_valD009.Where(x => x.D009 == 9).ToArray();            //Group2 = value '9'      to$22,000
        US_UserDataModel[] g3 = total_valD009.Where(x => x.D009 == 10).ToArray();           //Group3 = value '10'     to$24,000


        int total_d009 = total_valD009.Length;
        var tol_g1 = g1;
        var tol_g2 = g2;
        var tol_g3 = g3;
```

**I need to know how can I sum all total of g1, g2, g3

Comment: for which property you want to calculate sum?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the sum of D009 property for each group? Or do you want just to know how many items do you have in the each group?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this basic example to solve your problem.

```
class ClassName
{
    public int property = 1;
}

List<ClassName> ls = new List<ClassName>();

ls.Add(new ClassName());
ls.Add(new ClassName());
ls.Add(new ClassName());
ls.Add(new ClassName());
int sum = 0;
foreach(ClassName obj in ls)
{
    sum = sum + obj.property;
}
```